# does anyone have a real web-project working with Flow types?

Tags: flowtype, flow-typed

I have a simple web-project with React, webpac-dev-server, eslint, prettier, jest which is not acceptably working with Flow.

Any changes make Flow to calculate new decision during 4-5 minutes!
I made configurations for WebStorm and VSCode - situation with Flow in VSCode is better but not enough for developing code

I want to ensure that it's only my project's problem or it's a global situation

You can try my simple project in WebStorm and VSCode [here](https://github.com/budarin/react-ssr-bootstrap-project)
try to star client then server and then test-watch task and try to edit App.css

Comment: Are you running on windows?

Comment: yes, on windows

Comment: The truth is that flow doesn't really work on windows. There're multiple not resolved [issues](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3323) related to windows support that I don't believe will be ever addressed.

Comment: Flow should work fine/fast on windows. What version of Flow are you using?

Comment: @JamesKraus Flow server crashes on windows nearly every time you make some changes to tracked files. Have a look at [this](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/5583#issuecomment-374041843) comment from one of main flow contributors. _it crashes due to "Dfind_died". Dfind is the file watcher Flow uses. It sounds like it might be less than stable on Windows for some reason_ . There's even PR to update documentation, so it will clearly state that windows support is "limited".

Comment: @JamesKraus
The latest